# Why is the following bash script throws an error?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script :

```
#!/bin/sh

V=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
echo $V
```

It throws an error:

```
line 3: -Xmx2048m: command not found
```

How to correct it?

Comment: try http://shellcheck.net

Comment: To explain what you are doing: A line of the form `A=B C` executes the command C, but places the environment variable A (set to the value B) in the environment of the process running C. In your case, you are trying to run the command `-Xmx2048m` in an environment, where the variable `V` is set to `-Xms1024m`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
#!/bin/sh

V="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
echo "$V"
```

Your value contains space.